# Display Members and Value Members from Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am learning MVC 4 razor,i am trying to get display member and value from drop down list but i am not able to get it, this is my code

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).change(function ()
    {
        var selectedItem = $("#Employee :selected").text();
        var selectedValue = $("#Employee").val();
        alert(selectedItem+" "+selectedValue);
        //document.getElementById("#lblEmployee").innerText = selectedItem;
    });

</script>
@Html.DropDownList("Employee", ViewData["lstEmp"] as SelectList)
```

please help me out,If any other way rather using JQuery please tell.

Comment: what return `$("#Employee")`, `$("#Employee").val()`, `$("#Employee :selected")`, `$("#Employee :selected").text()` ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want pass value member to controller ,from controller to service so that i can get selected record on the basis of selected value member

Answer (score 0):

```
Controller:
    public ActionResult Create()
        {
        var VM = new ProjectViewModel();
        int projectId = 0;

        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "a" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "b" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "c" });

            VM.ddlClientLists = list
            return View("Create",VM);
        }
```

view model:

```
  public class VM
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> ddlClientLists { set; get; }
        public VM(){
            ddlClientLists = new List<SelectListItem>();          
        }
    }
```

in create view:

```
@model project.Models.VM
@Html.DropDownList("ddlclientLists", Model.ddlClientLists, "select")
```